# Laravel Eloquent persist 1:n

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, model

I want to create a laravel crud repository for a model. The model has 1 1:n and 1 n:n relationship.

```
 class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    protected $fillable = [
        'description', 'merchantId', 'name', 'link', 'pictureUrl', 'ean', 'brand', 'aktPrice', 'affiliatePortal', 'programId'
    ];

    public function prices() {
        return $this->hasMany(Price::class);
    }

    public function categories() {
        return $this->hasMany(Categorie::class);
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a repository which has a save method and a controller for a restapi, which calls the save methode. My question is how should a save method looks that the entity is saved correctly and which mapping operations have to be done before that it works. I hope someone can help me and send me a save method, or a crud repository for my case and can help me to design the controller.

Answer (score 0):

A Controller, with all the crud operations, look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Room;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RoomController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $rooms = Room::all()->toArray();
    return $rooms;
  }

  public function add(Request $request)
  {
    $room = new Room;
    $room->create($request->all());
    return response()->json('The room successfully added');
  }

  public function getById($id)
  {
    $room = Room::find($id);
    return response()->json($room);
  }

  public function update($id, Request $request)
  {
    $room = Room::find($id);
    $room->update($request->all());

    return response()->json('The room successfully updated');
  }

  public function delete($id)
  {
    $room = Room::find($id);
    $room->delete();

    return response()->json('The room successfully deleted');
  }
}
```

Comment: so if I have a 1:n relationship and the child entity is already persisted it is enough to use  $room->create($request->all()); to create the entity in the database ?

Comment: You are trying to create a **Price**  and a **Category** on the **Product** route? If the answer is yes. Then the controller that i show to you is not sufficient. You you need to call the repository of the both child, that will have their own save methods, and then save then. Have you heard about the repository pattern? here is a link about it: https://asperbrothers.com/blog/implement-repository-pattern-in-laravel/.